# Is there a way in android to execute an action when the user double clicks the power button?

Tags: android

In general there are three ways to interact with buttons in android. Normal click, long click and double click. Android by default assigns actions to normal click and double click of the power button.

In there a way to assign an action when the user double clicks the power button?